# Ansible: Building a dynamic HTML email template

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I hitting a roadblock with this task. I am working on a patch management playbook, that is doing a bunch of things, but I hitting the ceiling on building an email template, that uses tables, to report on the facts from the remote servers.

Here is the playbook and jinja2 template I am using:

```
---
- name: Send HTML Email with System Uptime and Inventory Hostname
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: yes

  vars: 
    success_servers: []
    server_hostname: []

  
  tasks:

    - name: Create custom fact
      set_fact:
        server_hostname: "{{ server_hostname + [inventory_hostname] }}"

    - name: Get system uptime
      shell: 'uptime | cut -f1-6 -d" "'
      register: uptime_result
    
    - name: Add server to success list if snapshot and patches were successful
      set_fact:
        success_servers: "{{ success_servers + [inventory_hostname] }}"
      when: uptime_result is defined
    
    - name: Get the total amount of updates remaining 
      shell: yum list updates | grep '^.' | wc -l
      register: updates_result   
    
    - name: Create jinja2
      template:
        src: templates/html.j2
        dest: email.html
      delegate_to: localhost
  
  post_tasks:

    - name: Send HTML email
      mail:
        host: "{{ smtp_server }}"
        port: 25
        subject: "System Uptime and Inventory Hostname"
        body: "{{ lookup('file', 'email.html') }}"
        from: "{{ from_email }}"
        to: "{{to_email }}"
        #content_type: html
        subtype: html
        charset: utf8
      delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: true
```

Here is a sample of the jinja2 template:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
        table {
            font-family: arial, sans-serif;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            width: 50%;
        }

        td, th {
            border: 1px solid #dddddd;
            text-align: left;
            padding: 8px;
        }

        th {
            background-color: #dddddd;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Servers successfully patched</h2>
        <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Hostname</th>
            <th>Uptime</th>
            <th>Successfully Snapped & Patched</th>
            <th>Remaining Updates</th>
        </tr>
        {% for host in groups['all'] %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ server_hostname }}</td>
            <td>{{ uptime_result }}</td>
            <td>{{ success_servers }}</td>
            <td>{{ updates_result.stdout }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

I believe I figured out how to dynamically populate the tables using the for-loop in the Jinja template, but here are the issues I am having:

1. By setting the run once statement to true, my jinja2 template is only populated with details from one server. I have a total of two servers in my inventory, so two tables are built, which is correct, but populated with the same server details twice. Which is normally the first server in my inventory list.
2. By removing the run_once statement, declaring it false, I am subject to receiving an email for the two servers I have in my inventory list, which builds two tables, with the same server details in each table. Basically, the same thing is happening in 1) but an email for however many servers would be in the inventory list. Based on the design, ansible will loop through all task on each server.

How would I accomplish this by populating the jinja2 template with all of the server names and details, but run it once? I thought about appending everything to a file using line in file module and cat the output to the email body, but it overcomplicates the play more than it needs to, or maybe I should take this route. How would you handle this?

Here is a sample of the email:
(ignore the uptime details I am working on this tee-hee)

[Output of the email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xeDra.png)

Edit: Here is a sample inventory:

```
[prod_servers]
90vmswipe1.com
90vmswipe2.com
```

Comment: Sorry, I can't follow what you're saying about the `run_once:` and "one server but twice" -- can you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75381051/edit) and include a sample inventory file that reproduces your behavior, or an `ansible-playbook -i` invocation that will turn your question into an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @mdaniel I edited my question. My apologies. I think I was too into what I was typing without noticing I was missing those details. Let me know what you think.

Answer (score 0):

Your set of tasks can basically be reduced to (untested, to be amended for your exact requirement). See the documentation for [magic var `ansible_play_hosts_all`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html):

```yaml
---
- name: Send HTML Email with System Uptime and Inventory Hostname
  hosts: all
  
  tasks:

    - name: Get system uptime
      shell: 'uptime | cut -f1-6 -d" "'
      register: uptime_result
    
    - name: Get the total amount of updates remaining 
      shell: yum list updates | grep '^.' | wc -l
      register: updates_result   
    
  post_tasks:

    - name: Send HTML email
      mail:
        host: "{{ smtp_server }}"
        port: 25
        subject: "System Uptime and Inventory Hostname"
        body: "{{ lookup('template', 'html.j2') }}"
        from: "{{ from_email }}"
        to: "{{ to_email }}"
        #content_type: html
        subtype: html
        charset: utf8
      delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: true
```

with a template which looks like (truncated to the relevant loop only):

```
        {% for host in ansible_play_hosts_all %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ hostvars[host].inventory_hostname }}</td>
            <td>{{ hostvars[host].uptime_result | d('N/A') }}</td>
            <td>{{ 'yes' if hostvars[host] uptime_result is defined else 'no' }}</td>
            <td>{{ hostvars[host].updates_result.stdout | d('No result') }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
```

Comment: When I try this out, I get the an error when running the lookup plugin looking for a template.

Comment: Where did you store the template exactly? I inferred it would stay in a `templates` directory adjacent to your playbook.

Comment: Hello! Template is in the templates directory. From a folder level, it looks like this playbooks/templates. I moved the file to playbooks/html.j2 and still recieved the same error, which was odd.